# Running Spring WS Samples on github results in maven errors

Tags: spring, maven, spring-ws, snapshot

I'm trying to run the mtom example on spring-ws: https://github.com/poutsma/spring-ws/tree/master/samples/mtom

under the `server` directory when I run `mvm:jetty run` I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.ws:mtom-server:2.1.4.RELEASE-SNAPSHOT (/Users/user/springws/spring-ws/samples/mtom/server/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar is missing. @ line 21, column 29
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 29
```

So I added versions to those in [pom.xml](https://github.com/poutsma/spring-ws/blob/master/samples/mtom/server/pom.xml)

```
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
```

But now when I again try to run `mvm:jetty run` I get the following error which I don't know how to resolve..

```
[INFO] >>> maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ mtom-server >>>
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mtom-server: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.ws:mtom-server:war:2.1.4.RELEASE-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: did you download the entire project? I can see it referes to its parent pom where it has most of the dependencies

Comment: I agree with @Vegard -- build from the parent pom, and if you wish to build only mtom then comment out the other modules in the parent pom's <modules> section

Comment: I did download the entire project. and then cd'd into the mtom project.

Comment: I think this might be an issue https://github.com/poutsma/spring-ws/blob/master/pom.xml#L88

Comment: did you do a "clean install" on the parent project before "mvn jetty:run?"

Comment: yeah, I tried that as well. I started again and got the code again to make sure I didn't mess anything up but still the same thing. Here is a gist of the two errors I get. I fixed the error in gistfile2.txt by adding versions. https://gist.github.com/Omnipresent/5584918

Comment: If you need to start a module from a multi-module project never cd into the module and do `mvn Whatever`. Better use `mvn -pl moduleName goal` or `mvn -pl moduldeName LifeCycle` may be in combination with `mvn -pl moduleName -amd XXX` to build things which might depend on the *moduleName`. Apart from that it looks you are trying to run some kind of integration tests which should be handled different.